# How to Extract Tabular Data From A PDF File With PyPDF2 and Python

Tags: python, regex, pypdf

So I have done this in Java before, but I am newer to python, so I need to know hoe to do the following:

I have a bunch of PDF files that my python script downloads from a website. Those PDF's contain product information on different products. Not all PDF's have the same categories/data. There is a category, Application, that spans 2 data lines in one PDF and 1 in the other. I am making dictionaries out of the data by collecting the one side and then the other and zipping them into a dictionary, however, since Application takes up 2 lines in one of the PDF's, I am forced to merge those separate list pieces into 1. However, if I do that for all of them, than the 1 lined one will get mixed with the next line. How can I make it sense if it is 1 or 2 lines and do something accordingly. Here is my code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
import re

pdf = PdfFileReader('C:/Users/CDS/tester.pdf')
text = pdf.getPage(0).extractText()

a = re.findall('Product Attributes(.*?)Minerallac Company', text, re.S)
b = re.findall('Tension Strength(.*?)FE:', text, re.S)

a = ''.join(a)
a = a.strip()
a = a.split('\n')
a[9] = a[9] + a[10]
a.remove(a[10])

b = ''.join(b)
b = b.strip()
b = b.split('\n')
b[4] = b[4] + b[5]
a.remove(a[5])

PDFData = dict(zip(a, b))

categories = ['Application', 'Finish', 'Brand Name']

for category in categories:
    print(category + ': ' + PDFData[category])
    print('\n')
```

[removed broken links]

As you can see, the application line has data of different lengths. One is 1 line and the other is 2 lines. How can I detect this with PyPDF2 and is there a better way to get the data than what I'm doing?

Sorry if it's a bit confusing, let me know if you don't understand something!

Comment: Could you paste few output lines how PyPDF shows the pdf around the "Application" section? Some of us may able to help from regexp side.

Comment: How can I copy it? I am running it in cmd. @zolo

Comment: Have you looked at pdfminer?

Comment: I did, but I found pypdf to be a little easier. I am more of a beginner at Python. Is there an easy way to do this with PDFMiner, and if so, where is the PDFMiner3k documentation, I haven't been able to find much of it. I am using python 3, so I need 3k, correct?

Comment: As the files are no longer accessible, it's not longer possible to understand what this question is about.